# How to check StartDate < EndDate using UoN.ExpressiveAnnotations

Tags: validation, razor, data-annotations, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.Net Core Razor pages and have a form on which the end date must be validated on the client side to be later than the start date.

The rest of the form is being validated using UoN.ExpressiveAnnotations.

The dates are defined as follows :

```
 [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
 [Required]
 public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } 

 [Display(Name = "End Date")]
 [Required]
 public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

I have tried using

```
[RequiredIf("EndDate > StartDate", ErrorMessage = "End must be later than Start")]
```

with the End Date declaration, but this does not provide the validation necessary.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DOH.  I was missing something obvious.
It should have been

```
AssertThat
```

not

```
RequiredIf
```